# Graphql/Apollo/React unable to import local images

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I just started playing around with Graphql/Apollo few days ago and today I got this problem. I have big nav bar which has icon for every link. there are my code:

```
let nav_options = [
{
 name: 'Dashboard',
 image: 'pictures/icons/dashboard.png',
 link: '/#'
},
{
 name: 'Report',
 image: './pictures/icons/dashboard.png',
 link: '/#'
},
]
```

and then

```
export const Routes = () => (
 <Router>
  <div class="app-container">
   <nav class="main-menu">
    <ul>
    {nav_options.map(option => (
      <li>
        <Link to={option.link}>
        <input className="icon" type="image" src={option.image} />
          <span class="nav-text">
            {option.name}
          </span>
        </Link>
      </li>
    ))}
```

{option.name} and {option.link} working perfectly. I feel like i'm missing something.?

I FIXED IT: and this is how

```
image: require('pictures/icons/dashboard.png'),
```

Comment: Why are you using input tag?

Comment: it doesnt matter, it work with <img> aswell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need require or import the images.

```
    let nav_options = [ 
{ 
 name: 'Dashboard',
 image: require('pictures/icons/dashboard.png'),
 link: '/#'
}, 
{ 
 name: 'Report',
 image: require ('./pictures/icons/dashboard.png'), 
link: '/#' 
}, 
]
```

Comment: thank you so much! I just randomly did same thing myself before I saw your post. This just looking weird to me tho lol

Comment: It is about how JavaScript bundlers work. I guess you are webpack or something equivalent

Comment: Hehe. Sorry typo. I meant you were using webpack.